Arduino 3x4 matrix keypad stopped working
I think I might just need a new keypad. Earlier this morning I had my keypad working perfectly. I printed a new housing for it, transferred it, plugged it back in (I thought I did this all correctly). It worked for a bit, would stop working, and then randomly start working again. I would even double check that it still functioned by plugging it into a different arduino. However, now it seems to just be a fancy brick with some buttons. Is it possible that I bricked the matrix keypad by pressing multiple keys at once? is there a chance I damaged multiple Arduinos? Here is my wiring schematic and code. Please look at my code for the correct pinouts, however the colors are the same in both diagrams.
#include <Keypad.h>

const byte ROWS = 4;
const byte COLS = 3;

char hexaKeys[ROWS][COLS] = {
{ '1', '2', '3' },
{ '4', '5', '6' },
{ '7', '8', '9' },
{ '.', '0', '#' }
};

/*
2 = red = 26
3 = green = 28
4 = blue = 38
5= yellow = 32
6 = orange = 34
7 = purple = 36
8 = black = 38
*/
//byte rowPins[ROWS] = { 39, 29, 31, 35 };//{ 7, 2, 3, 5 };
//byte colPins[COLS] = { 37, 41, 33 };//{ 6, 8, 4 };


const int red = 2;
const int green = 3;
const int blue = 4;
const int yellow = 5;
const int orange = 6;
const int purple = 7;
const int black = 8;
byte rowPins[ROWS] = { purple, red, green, blue };
byte colPins[COLS] = { orange, black, blue };

Keypad customKeypad = Keypad(makeKeymap(hexaKeys), rowPins, colPins, ROWS, COLS);

void setup() {
Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
char customKey = customKeypad.getKey();

if (customKey) {
Serial.println(customKey);
}
}


Well we don't know what broke or is it just a loose connection or incorrect wiring. Your code may be fine but the real implementation is hidden behind the Arduino wall of libraries. Do you know how the Arduino code scans the matrix? Where is the Arduino library code to see if there is danger for damage when two or more buttons are pushed.

Test the Arduino without a keypad by just connecting a row pin to a col pin. Does that work?

Hello, I cannot find any reason for a potential damage here. Maybe your keypad has some issues. You can use a standard 4x4 matrix keypad instead: https://www.theengineeringprojects.com/2017/08/arduino-keypad-interfacing.html

Please take your keypad housing back off, and expose the inner electronics, and then take a picture of top, bottom and any side that can help show the inner workings of the circuit. Also, while the housing is off, plug the keypad back in and test it again. Finally, if you can analyze the circuit with your continuity tester and create a schematic, that would be invaluable to us for being able to help you. You have an internal problem, but you really have shown us only the externals.
